# Mожно ли сочитать несколько условий в зависимости от значений параметров?

Tags: sql, oracle

Можно ли сочитать несколько условий в зависимости от значений параметров?

Есть условие:

```
and (:x is null or ','||:x||',' like '%,'||column3||',%')
```

То есть, что пытаюсь сделать, сейчас произвожу выборку по условию `:x` в колонке `column3`. Мне нужно проверить `:x`, если допустим будет равен `all`, то произвести выборку по определённым значениям. Например:

```
column3` in ('value1', 'value2')
```

В [этом примере с данными](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d93c521465accec295f26fdcf49da867) пытаюсь отфильтровать несколько условий
такого вида:

```
where df in (decode(:x, 'Other', 'vol1'), 'vol2')
```

И получаю нужный мне результат, но, затрудняюсь дальше с ветвлением, соответсвенно, если `:x` будет `vol3` или `vol2` выполнить выборку по ним, а если `:x` равен 'Other', то выполнить по заданным значениям, допустим ('vol4','vol5'). И попытаться учесть то, что может быть передано несколько условий, 'vol1' и `Other`, и тогда выполнить выборку по обоим.

Возможно ли реализовать подобное?

Comment: Как я знаю, по крайней мере в ms sql, нельзя использовать `if` в `where`. Вот что нашлось по Вашему запросу https://coderoad.ru/39788415/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-IF-THEN-ELSE-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-where-%D0%B2-Oracle

Comment: Или же вариант использовать `case` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396217/if-statement-within-where-clause

Comment: @MaxDown, хм, вариант case больше нравится, буду пробовать

Comment: @MaxDown, чтото не один из способов не помог, при условии что должно вернутся в than одно условие все работает, но если нужно несколько с этим уже проблемы

Comment: Приведите примеры исправленного кода. Знатоки oracle помогут

Comment: @MaxDown, я пытался реализовать ветвления путем:
where column3 in (case when :x = 'all' then 'value1' end), но, в данном в then нельзя несколько значений передать, один вариант приблизил к решению, если следующем путем column3 in (decode(case when :x = 'all' then 'value1' end), 'value2'), но это не совсем то, так как с all может быть передано значение которое нужно использовать в качестве фильтра что не подходит под данную логику,

Comment: На [фиддле](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ab5117ac12016a4ae0cd2d85d60c6964) добавте данные и попытку решения.

Comment: @0xdb Здравствуйте, [https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cd9b3346a0268efbcb4744590da30875], добавил простой пример, `where df in (decode(dat, 1234, 'vol1'), 'vol2')` в данном случае получается сделать выборку по нескольким условием если использовать `decode` но с остальным ветвлением затрудняюсь, на бинд `:x` передаются переменные и если к примеру значение all пытаюсь пройти по определённым('value1', 'value2'), но так же может быть передан одновременно  value3 и all также пытаюсь учесть,

Comment: @0xdb p.s. `decode(dat, 1234,` выполнил так на фиддле, не знаю как правильно банды использовать там

Comment: Честно говоря, не понял, что там не так на фиддле? Не пишите комментарии, дополняйте сам вопрос.

Comment: @0xdb у меня не получилось реализовать `:x` бинд на фиде, поэтому взял заведомо истинное условие для decode для отладки,
обновил вопрос, расписал что пытаюсь реализовать, пре-проверка условий и выборку уже на основе переданного значение, затруднение в ветвление и реализации передачи листа условий, встречал что пытались выполнить подобное через sys.ODCIVarchar2List('value1','value2')

Comment: Вроде начинаю понимать, но не уверен, что до конца. Например, в вопросе упомнуто Other, а на фиддле это значение отсутствует, почему?

Comment: _не получилось реализовать :x бинд на фиддле_, используете просто литералы.

Comment: @0xdb, не получилось реализовать банды на фиде, я взял заведомо истинное условие, т.е. decode(dat, 1234, 'vol1') в колонке dat есть значение 1234 поэтому истинно присваиваю df in 'vol1','vol2' , соответсвенно фильтрация выполнена,

Comment: Вы не ответили на вопрос из предыдущего комментерия - что вы ожидаете с Other, почему это значение отсутствует на фиддле?

Comment: @0xdb, обновил фидл, добавил Other как условие, соответ. where df in (decode(dat, 'Other', 'vol1'), 'vol2')
если dat = Other сработает выборка для df in ('vol1', 'vol2')

Comment: Думал, что понял, теперь понял, что ничего не понял. Посторайтесь поставить чёткий вопрос, что есть, что надо добится, то  есть, что ожидается как результат. И всё в вопросе и на фиддле, а не в комментариях.

Comment: Сейчас на работе, вечером попробую предложить что-то, как я это понял.

Comment: @0xdb, аналогично, я пытаюсь реализовать подобное ветвление, если передано в dat = Other то выборка df in ('vol1', 'vol2'), если в dat передано любое другое значение, выполнить выборку по нему(dat = vol5 то выборка df in ('vol5')), если в переданых значениях есть vol5 и Other выборка df in ('vol1', 'vol2', 'vol5),
отчего изначально утончил, возможно ли сочитать and и if, выше предлагали выполнить через case, я пробовал вот так, но не вышло и как быть с другими ветками условий 
 [https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c73d67c0d8ff39c44690118873e7b6a8]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7ce078ed963a96f8297a1a761a63fbc4)):

```
with params (par1, par2) as (
    select sys.ODCIVarchar2List('vol1','vol2'), 'vol3' from dual 
)
select two.* from two, params
where df in (
    select column_value from table (par1) union all
    select par2         from dual
    )
```

CTE тут только заменяет переменные связывания, в реальном запросе `:par1 ... :par1`.

Comment: на основе вашего ответа получилось решить ветвление, также, еще получилось подобным способом
`
(
instr(:x_bind,column3)>0 or
(
(instr(:x_bind,'Other')>0 and 
column3 in ('vol1', ''vol8')
or
(instr(:x_bind,'Other') = 0)
)
)
)
`